# Responsive iframe for Mapbox service

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, mapbox

I need you help.

I'm a colombian data journalist with some basic knowledges on HTML, CSS and JS but I've been trying to solve this issue for hours without an answer. I already looked at here and other forums but couldn't make it work.

I created this map with Mapbox JS that shows some data about bachelors degree performance in all the states of Colombia

http://jsfiddle.net/camilomoreno/rcae1jpo/

Here is my Iframe

```
<iframe src="http://camilomorenokuratomi.com/infographics/coleducacion/mapbox.html" height="600" width="900" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

What I want is to make this map responsive. I'm only interested in shrinking the size of the map,but keeping the ratio, like I have seen for youtube videos and even google maps, but  sadly I couldn't repeat the same process with my map.

Could you please lend me a hand?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into this issue too, and tried these two things:

1. adding   meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"   into the head
2. adding a column size for mobile and desktop in my div 
   div class=".col-xs-4 .col-lg-8"

and it worked...

see "mixed mobile and tablet" - http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/  for additional help

P.S. stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to include the greater than and less signs

Comment: Sorry Team, I never say your answer until today. Thanks for the help, I will ckeck that up.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, can you show what you are trying to do with code?

Resizing your iframe should not be affecting ratio. If it is happening that the iframe is correctly resizing but your map inside of it doesnt, then try and refresh that map.